# App read only in Django admin when it should not

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My problem: when I deploy my webpage and set `DEBUG = False` in `settings.py` then go To the admin interface I only see black entries for the model of one app. Just as if I had set `has_change_permission(): return False`. However I did not set any `has_X_permission`. Though I did try to add `has_change_permission(): return True` to enforce it without success.

I do not get any error. The problem seems to only appear when deployed with apache at least I'm not able to reproduce the problem in combination with the embedded `manage.py runserver` webserver.

As I don't get any error I'm somewhat stuck :(

Some more Information:

edit what works and what does not:

- manage.py runserver `DEBUG=True` **works**
- manage.py runserver `DEBUG=False` **works**
- apache              `DEBUG=True`  **works**
- apache              `DEBUG=False` **does not work**

The code that generates the models:

```
class Belegung(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    bemerkung = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    begin = models.DateField()
    ende = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self): ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Belegungen"
        ordering = ['begin']


class CalendarContent(mainpage.ContentBlock):
    month = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self): ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): ...
    def headline(self): ...
    def nexturl(self): ...
    def prevurl(self): ...
    def extract_begin_end(self, entries, day):...
    def weeks(self): ...


class BelegungAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "bemerkung", "begin", "ende"]
    list_filter = ["begin"]
admin.site.register(Belegung, BelegungAdmin)


class CalendarContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('content_type',)
    pass
admin.site.register(CalendarContent, CalendarContentAdmin)
```

In the `settings.py` I included the app to installed apps.

In `DEBUG=True` mode everything works as expected. When `DEBUG=False` and deployed on apache webserver the models entries are black. However I can still use the already entered models on the webpage.

The models seem simple enough the methods in `CalendarContent` are for additional db-queries from the template...

Is there a place where I have to unlock my app to be read and write?

What are possible reasons that can make an app readonly?

Comment: do you see anything on the apache error logs? Also, i dont think it has anything to do with `DEBUG` mode. Just try turning `DEBUG=True` on the apache webserver

Comment: The apache error logs are not helpful. The strange thing is that it works on apache with DEBUG=True but does not with Debug=False.

Comment: Same problem here. I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the workaround... I filed a bugreport in the bugtracker but that experience was rather disappointing... https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue. It appears that the lack of a separate admin.py file causes this issue. An admin.py file isn't mandatory according to the documentation but it somehow causes this problem.